# .NET Clean architecture - multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, clean-architecture

I try do my projects with clean architecture. I use Entity Framework. Everything is good and easy to know. I have structure like this - Domain, Application, Infrastructure etc. I create my project without any big problems - WebApi project. Now I would like to add Blazor server side project. What is the right way? Only add Blazor project to my existing solution? Here is few problems for me. I will have the logic of two applications linked (handlers). And I have some nuget packages which contains webapi specializations. When I create own solution for blazor app here is only one problem. The duplicate of dbcontext. I need "duplicate" (I can use only 2 tables if I need) domain project with entites and dbcontext in infrastructure. But then it work's good and it's clear. But I don't think it's good way to duplicate domain project. And where is stored migrations?

I know if projects will microservices it will be super clear and it's makes sense. But when I have monolith and would like WebApi and Blazor app with one database what's right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the right way?

As always - it depends.

In the [Uncle Bob's article on the Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) the following point is present:

> Independent of UI. The UI can change easily, without changing the rest of the system. A Web UI could be replaced with a console UI, for example, without changing the business rules.

If your Blazor App can be considered just another UI (without major changes to the business rules, though it can have some specific use cases) then it should be a part of the current solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was Studying a course in PluralSight in clean-architecture by Gill Cleeren, they  the Blazor project to the same solution

Answer (score 1):

The point of Clean Architecture is that you do not have to duplicate shared logic. Blazor server project is a "front-end" layer at the edge of your application. If implemented correctly you will reference the other projects just like your WebAPI does.

Try to add a Blazor Server project to your solution and reference the Application/Infrastructure/Domain projects that already exist and you should be able to re-use all the exisitng logic.

Blazor (and WebAPI) is nothing more than a way to present your data, so keep it that way.